# SpringMVC, How to disable object parameter initialization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Now I want to use URL to transfer parameters and the parameters contain the object type. I need to judge whether the object type is empty. If it is not empty, enter the code block. But SpringMVC will automatically construct it. It makes me very upset. I try to use `@ModelAttribute` to initialize it，but when I get the parameter have been initialized. I need it not to initialize it.

How to deal with it?

Thank you very much!

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class ResourceController extends BaseAction {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceSer resourceSer;
    @Autowired
    private AddressSer addressSer;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ResourceController.class);


    /**
     * @Author: 
     * @Description: 查询所有能查看的资源 通过前端将eqMap, likeMap, btnMap转为json传递至后端，再转为相应的map进行查询
     * @Date: Created on 2017/7/21
     * @Version: 1.0
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resources", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String resources(String eq, String neq, String like, String btn, Pager pager, HttpSession session) {
        logger.info(" -------------------- /resource/resources --------------------");
        logger.info(" resources pager : " + pager);
        //if (!validSite(eq) || !validAuthorL(session, 3)) return UserController.error(session);
        eq = decode(eq);
        neq = decode(neq);
        like = decode(like);
        btn = decode(btn);
        logger.info(" resources 参数 eq : " + eq + " neq : " + neq + " like : " + like + " btn : " + btn);
        List<Resource> resources = resourceSer.findByDynamic(getMap(eq), getMap(neq), getMap(like), getMapList(btn), null, pager).getDatas();
        String json = JSON.toJSONString(resources, SerializerFeature.DisableCircularReferenceDetect);
        logger.info(" resources 结果 json : " + json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

When I visit http://localhost:8080/resource/resources, it is not null.

```
2017-08-10 14:55:37 -1576140 [http-bio-8088-exec-7] INFO    -  -------------------- /resource/resources --------------------
2017-08-10 14:55:37 -1576891 [http-bio-8088-exec-7] INFO    -  resources pager : com.chaoxing.core.util.Pager@3e17d44b
```

Access this action anyway,the pager is not null.
I hope that when the access parameter does not have 'pager', the 'pager' is null.

Comment: can u pls put some code in your question

Comment: Has been added, please see